# How to make selected link in Navigation highlighted when clicked

Tags: php, html, css, navigation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I highlight a link based on the current page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180887/how-do-i-highlight-a-link-based-on-the-current-page)

## Context

I have been trying for ages to get a selected link in my Navigation menu to stay highlighted when clicked, but I cant find any decent understandable tutorials on this.

## Questions

- How can I resolve this?
- Would jQuery or PHP be best for this?

## Code

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="aboutus.php">ABOUT US</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="aboutus.php">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="team.php">Team</a></li>
            <li><a href="careers.php">Careers</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="ourwork.php">OUR WORK</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="ourwork.php">Portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="upcoming.php">Upcoming</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="whatsnew.php">WHATS NEW</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="whatsnew.php">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd say use JavaScript or jQuery and just add a CSS class to the element to be highlighted.

Comment: or you can do it with css and html only. Lots of ways to go about it

Comment: see this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp

Comment: It's not possible without server side processing.

Comment: actually can you clarify this a bit, if I clicked on about us link, it will take me to that page and you want the about us link to be highlighted right? or did you want another kind of behavior?

Comment: @SheikhHeera you can do it without server side but your code will suck

Comment: How if you are loading the page from the server.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The cleaner is to add a `current` class to selected link when you generate the page on the server side.

## Example

I found this example which is close to your current architecture, according to the code that you gave us.

Source: http://www.finalwebsites.com/tutorials/css-navigation-bar.php

**PHP**

```php
$items = array(
    array('link'=>'scripts.html', 'label'=>'PHP scripts'), 
    array('link'=>'tutorials.html', 'label'=>'Tutorial'), 
    array('link'=>'template.html', 'label'=>'CSS template'), 
    array('link'=>'examples.html', 'label'=>'Code examples')
);

$menu = '<ul>';

foreach ($items as $val) {
    $class = ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == $val['link']) ? ' class="current"' : '';
    $menu .= sprintf('<li><a href="%s">%s</a></li>', $val['link'], $val['label']);
}

$menu .= '</ul>';

echo $menu;
```

**CSS**

```css
ul li a.current { background-color: #40611F; color: #FFFFFF; }
```